# enable to get stored session using redis with nodejs

Tags: node.js, session, express, share

I am developing a simple application with NodeJs and expressJs.
I followed this tutorial : http://blog.arisetyo.com/?p=492, I copyed the same code, I just execute my login form in localhost: 8080 and my nodejs server localhost: 8083 .when I click on the button I login succeeds and i can create a session and save the parameters in, but when I want to get the parameters of the session by going to '' / session / get / "I always have this message" no session value Stored in Redis ":(
someone can answer me please.

Comment: No one have a solution?

Comment: i need a solution please